# Why does using f32::consts::E give error E0223 but std::f32::consts::E does not?

Tags: compiler-errors, rust, traits

If I write:

```
let x = f32::consts::E;
```

I get the error:

```
error[E0223]: ambiguous associated type
  --> src/main.rs:32:21
   |
32 |             let x = f32::consts::E;
   |                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ help: use fully-qualified syntax: `<f32 as Trait>::consts`
```

But if I instead write:

```
let x = std::f32::consts::E;
```

Then everything is fine. The error message is confusing because, as I understand it, `f32` is a specific concrete type not a trait. I'm not sure why I would be using some special trait syntax.

What does the compiler think I'm doing and why does my fix help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What does the compiler think I'm doing

There is a *module* called `f32` and there is a *type* called `f32`. The type is available everywhere by default, the module is not.

With no additional imports, `f32::foo` is best understood by the compiler as an *associated type* for the type `f32`, but there's no such type. It assumes that the associated type comes from a trait and it suggests you be more explicit about what trait it is.

When you do `std::f32`, the path brings the module into scope and the nested module `consts` can then be found. You can also do:

```
use std::f32;
let x = f32::consts::E;
```

This can occur for any type, but usually types and modules use different naming styles (`UpperCamelCase` vs `snake_case`):

```
struct my_type;

mod other {
    pub mod my_type {
        pub mod consts {
            pub const ZERO: i32 = 0;
        }
    }
}

fn example() {
    my_type::consts::ZERO;
}
```

```
error[E0223]: ambiguous associated type
  --> src/lib.rs:12:5
   |
12 |     my_type::consts::ZERO;
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ help: use fully-qualified syntax: `<my_type as Trait>::consts`
```

It just happens that the primitives use all lower case.

Here's some code (of dubious usefulness) that shows how the associated type might actually happen:

```
struct Consts;

impl Consts {
    const E: char = 'e';
}

trait Example {
    type consts;
}

impl Example for f32 {
    type consts = Consts;
}

fn example() {
    <f32 as Example>::consts::E;
}
```

Comment: interesting that it assumes an associated type from a trait. if there were an impl that had been imported that caused f32 to implement a trait that had a foo type associated with it, would `f32::foo` be valid or do you always have to be explicit about it?

Comment: @JosephGarvin I don't immediately see how to make it use the non-explicit syntax, no.

Comment: @JosephGarvin Associated types don't resolve, but function calls do. I'm not sure why this difference. [Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=35bb29ab117ee11abe3c498dafaef34c)